# Computing partial derivatives of a trained neural network with TensorFlow v2

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, gradient

I want to compute the first and second order derivatives of a function that is approximated by a deep neural networks. I tried with an easy example, where we can clearly see what is the correct answer:
Suppose that the function to be approximated by the neural network is : y=x^2
Then, I construct the network as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import math
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Input
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model, Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras import losses

m_test=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14])
n_test= m_test**2

def model_gen(Input_shape):
    X_input = Input(shape=Input_shape)
    X = Dense(units=128, activation='relu')(X_input)
    X = Dense(units=64, activation='relu')(X)
    X = Dense(units=32, activation='relu')(X)
    X = Dense(units=1)(X)
    model = Model(inputs=X_input, outputs=X)
    return model

model = model_gen(Input_shape=(1,))
opt = Adam(lr=0.01, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, decay=0.001)
model.compile(loss=losses.mean_squared_error, optimizer=opt)
model.fit(m_test,n_test, epochs=1000)
```

After training the model, I calculate the derivatives using GradientTape() as follows:

```
x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
x = tf.convert_to_tensor(x, np.float32)
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    tape.watch(x)
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape2:
        tape2.watch(x)
        y = model(x)
    grad_y = tape2.gradient(y, x)
grad_y2 = tape.jacobian(grad_y,x)    
print(y)
print(grad_y)
print(grad_y2)
```

Here is the results:

```
tf.Tensor(
[[ 1.1044241]
 [ 4.0293255]
 [ 8.592318 ]
 [16.362782 ]
 [24.958858 ]
 [36.002636 ]], shape=(6, 1), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([ 0.9645251  2.2506325  7.7348967  7.901049   9.065702  11.975435 ], shape=(6,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]], shape=(6, 6), dtype=float32)
```

Though the first order derivative is somewhat acceptable (there are errors), the second derivative is 0, which is definitely wrong because we know that the second order derivative of the function y=x^2 is always 2.

I would be very appreciated if someone can help me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You are putting too much faith that the model learned the function y=x^2, which is not what was learned, specially if you used such a small dataset.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Thanks for the comment. Yes, I can make the model better, but it is just an illustration for people to understand. My question is why the second derivative is 0, it could be anything, right or wrong, but the whole jacobian matrix is 0 is something abnormal.

Comment: Your entire network uses `relu` activations. Think about what the second derivative of that (a piece-wise linear function) is.

Comment: @xdurch0 Thanks for comment. I changed the activations to sigmoid, and you are right, now the jacobian matrix is not 0 anymore. However, the second order derivative is far from correct, and the first order derivative is almost correct if we round them up. So, do you have some ideas on how to compute the second derivative correctly?

Comment: I don't think there is anything to fix here. You are computing the second derivative of the _network_, not the target function, and this may be different. In particular, you are fitting a simple function on a very small dataset, meaning your model is most likely heavily overfit as it has way too many parameters. It does _not_ learn x^2, it just learns some function that is close to x^2 on the training inputs.